# Is it appropriate to use "ecological" word as adjective outside of ecological context

Tags: writing-style

Is it possible to use the word "ecological" as an adjective in a context that doesn't refer to pure ecology? Example: using the expression «An ecological approach» in software engineering to refer to an approach that has components that can be reuse in software engineering.

Comment: Of course it's possible. You just did. The issue is whether it's meaningful, but that would seem to depend on a variety of specific factors that make this question seem to me to be unanswerable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about word usage and not academics.

Comment: WRT your specific example, note that '[Ecology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_ecosystem)' already has a metaphorical meaning in the software engineering community. It also has [terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse) for what you are trying to express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ecological](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ecological) has two main usages: the first refers to ecology, the science that  studies the the relationship between organisms and their enviroment:

> - 1. (Environmental Science) of or relating to ecology.

and the behaviour, especially human behaviour, that may affect the natural environment:

> - 2. (Environmental Science) (of a practice, policy, product, etc) tending to benefit or cause minimal damage to the environment.

AHD

In your sentence you are referring to human behaviour that may have a positive impact on saving or use more efficiently electronic/digital resources and, I think,  the "ecological" concept might  rightly be called into question even though I'd probably refer to it as an  "efficient approach".